# Setting a property of external HTML element to a component property value in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, property-binding

I am trying to use an external HTML element inside the HTML of a component in my Angular app.

So I import the external library by adding the following snippet to my `index.html` file:

```
<script src="https://embed.xxx.co/bundle.js"></script>
```

In my `app.component.html` file, I use the HTML element like this:

```
<dashboard welcome-message="hello"></dashboard>
```

This works successfully!

However, when I now want to pass a variable to the external HTML, I define the property in my Angular component `app.component.ts` file like this:

```
message: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.message = "Hello";
}
```

And then in the `app.component.html` file, I pass the component property to the HTML like this (as described here - https://angular.io/guide/property-binding):

```
<dashboard [welcome-message]="message"></dashboard>
```

The problem is that this does not work. The `welcome-message` property is not binding properly, and when I inspect the `<dashboard>` element in the UI, the `welcome-message` property is missing.

It's really weird, as for example when using the `<img>` element, binding to the img `src` property works fine using the approach above.

I am using Angular v13.

Any ideas on what is going on here or what the problem is?

I have looked up everything online and I can't find an answer!

Comment: Is `welcome-message` an attribute or an Input() property?

Comment: Also, I would suggest using camel casing for declaring properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Anglesvar. So `welcome-message` is a property of a HTML element from an external library, which is not written in Angular. I am just reading the docs of the library (I can't share the library name unfortunately), and it says that `welcome-message` is a property of the `<dashboard>` element. Could it be that this library is not designed to work with Angular? 

The library docs say "The dashboard web component is a custom HTML element. This means that it functions as a native HTML element and can be used in any web development context."

Comment: Then I think "welcome-message" is an attribute, you might have to pass it like this
    `<dashboard [attr.welcome-message]="message"></dashboard>`

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your `dashboard`. If it's not an Angular component really I don't not if can work get the element in javascript and give value

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.message = "Hello";
  const dashboard=document.getElementsByTag("dashboard")
  if (dashboard && dashboard.length)
  {
      dashboard[0]['welcome-message']=this.message
      //or, if not work
      dashboard[0].setAttribute('welcome-message',this.message)

  }
  else
     console.log("I coudn't find the dashboard")
}
```

NOTE: See that each change in "this.message" you should make the same. You can use a getter
private _message;

```
set message(value) {
    this._message = value;
    const dashboard = document.getElementsByTagName("dashboard");
    if (dashboard && dashboard.length) {
        dashboard[0].setAttribute('welcome-message', value);
        //or, if not work
        dashboard[0].setAttribute('welcome-message', this._message);
    } else {
        console.log("I coudn't find the dashboard");
    }
}

get message() {
    return this._message;
}
```

Comment: Why not use attribute binding directly?
https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding

Comment: @Anglesvar, I think that the question is related to a **no angular component**,  If was an Angular component you are Ok. If is an Angular element (or any similar) you need get as any html element and change the "attribute"